# Async method in Main returns immediately

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await

I have the following Main in a net core 2.2 app, using c# level 7.3

```
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        _logger.TraceMethodBegins(nameof(Main));
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;
        TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException;
        using (ServiceFactory.Instance)
        {
            try
            {
                Parser.Default.ParseArguments<Options>(args)
                    .WithParsed(async o =>
                    {
                        IWtgValuesCalculator wtgValuesCalculator = ServiceFactory.Instance.Kernel.Get<IWtgValuesCalculator>();
                        await wtgValuesCalculator.Calculate(o.StartDate, o.EndDate, o.FacilityName);
                    })
                    .WithNotParsed(async o =>
                    {
//Code enters over here
                        IWtgValuesCalculator wtgValuesCalculator = ServiceFactory.Instance.Kernel.Get<IWtgValuesCalculator>();
                        await wtgValuesCalculator.Calculate(null, null, null);
                    });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.Fatal(e, e.Message);
            }
        }
//And jump here immediately without awaiting
        _logger.TraceMethodEnds(nameof(Main));
    }
```

The method is returning immediately, without awaiting for `await wtgValuesCalculator.Calculate()` I have verified that there are no exceptions, if I change it to use all sync methods, the program runs as expected. Also, calling `wtgValuesCalculator.Calculate(o.StartDate, o.EndDate, o.FacilityName).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`make it run correctly. A colleague tells me that he read somewhere that async methods in Main might have problems because mscorlib not been fully loaded, but I can't find any info about it. Anyone can bring some light about it?
Kind regards.

Comment: One would expect that, if this was built to work with `async` that whatever was returned by the chain after `ParseArguments` would be awaitable. If that were so, though, you'd expect to get a warning. Your lambdas are almost certainly effectively converting to something `async void`, so there's no way to tell when they're finished.

Comment: It looks like you're hitting [this code](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline/blob/master/src/CommandLine/ParserResultExtensions.cs#L21), which invokes your delegate with no cares as to whether or not it's `await`able.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Interesting.. So, if I download the source and create an async implementation, I can expect it to work correctly?

Comment: In theory, yes, but rather than fork an existing open source library, wouldn't it be easier to just take the result of ParseArguments and use it rather use the WithParsed and WithNotParsed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever await appears, your method is being split into 2: before the await and after the await (it's not 100% accurate, but close enough). The "second" method will be executed once the awaited operation is done, and the "first" part returns when the awaited operation returns the awaitable.
To make the whole method call chain wait for the"second" parts, you need to have an await on every awaitable method up the call tree.

Answer (score 0):

You await in the async methods you pass to `WithParsed` and `WithNotParsed`. You don't await anywhere inside your `async Main` method.

Parse your args and then `await wtgValuesCalculator.Calculate` inside Main.

In other words: At the moment you send two async methods to WithParsed/WithNotParsed and continue without awaiting in Main. Your `await`only in the context of the WithParsed/WithNotParsed delegates.